# return 403 error if isAuthenticated() == false

Tags: java, spring, configuration, spring-security

I have this spring security configuration:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

        <intercept-url pattern="/home.jsp" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/loginFailed" access="permitAll" /> 
        <intercept-url pattern="/logOut" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="isAuthenticated()" /> 

    <form-login login-page="/home.jsp" default-target-url="/index"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginFailed" />
        <logout  logout-success-url="/logOut"/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="N_a" password="12" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

If I type url, that need `access="isAuthenticated()` I redirect to `home.jsp`.
 I want to see 403 error.
How to change it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a form-based login and as such, when not authenticated, you will be prompted with the login-page. This is what you have configured and this is how, by default, Spring Security works.

If you want to override this you need to explicitly configure an `AuthenticationEntryPoint` to  be precise the `Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint`. This basically always gives a 403 if someone isn't authenticated or doesn't have access. This disables the ability to be prompted with a login-form to give a user the change to login after all.

```
<beans:bean id="entryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint" />

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="entryPoint"> 
<!-- Your other elements here -->
</http>
```

Comment: if I write these code in my configuration:  cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'bean'.

Comment: `<beans:bean` instead of `<bean` as you have used spring security as the root namespace. (Modified answer.

Answer (score 0):

use **access-denied-handler** tag in **http** tag.

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/customize-http-403-access-denied-page-in-spring-security/

or use **access-denied-page** property.

```
<http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/403"></http>
```